# Dismiss a video WkWebview after finish

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello Everyone i'm trying to set up an onclick button so that the video will lunch, and it's working perfectly.

but i don't know how to procede to exit from the it after the video end up.

```
@IBAction func playvideo(_ sender: Any) {
         
         let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
               webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
               webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
         let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
            
        
         myPlayer = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: window.frame.origin.x, y: window.frame.origin.y, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))

         self.view.addSubview(myPlayer)
         
         if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: ".mp4") {
             let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)
         
             
                    let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: filePathURL)
                    myPlayer.load(request)
            
               }
```

i will be grateful if you can help me

Comment: This is a local URL on your device, why do you need WKWebView for playing this?

Comment: i didn't understand your question , if i'm not using WKWebView how can i procede ?  in my application when a user click on play button the video should display .

Comment: I see you're accessing your video resource from your bundle

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WKScriptMessageHandler` in order to catch the video ending and performing the exit you desire to do.

Here's Apple documentation about this topic:
[WKScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler)

This means you'll have to implement a message delivery to the client on your video site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will try that.